Assigning products to constants or variables in Maple
I am doing Ito calculus workings in Maple. With B__t as a standard Brownian motion, the following results are true:
dB__t*dt = 0;
dB__t^2 = dt;
dt^2 = 0;

Now when I want to do the assignment:
dB__t*dt := 0;
dB__t^2 := dt;
dt^2 := 0;

I get the error message Error, illegal use of an object as a name. Why the need of the above assignments? Suppose I have:
Y__t := ln(1/X__t - 1);

dX__t := 0.5*X__t(-X__t + 1)*(-2*X__t + 1)*dt - X__t*(-X__t + 1)*dB__t;

Applying Ito's lemma on Y__t:
dY__t := diff(Y__t, t)*dt + diff(Y__t, X__t)*dX__t + 0.5*diff(Y__t, X__t, X__t)*dX__t^2

and expanding and simplying using:
dY__t := simplify(expand(dY__t))

yields:

Now that I have an expanded dY__t expression, I want to then replace dt*dB__t,  dB__t*dt and dt^2 with zero and to replace dB__t^2 with dt. How do I do that?

Here are two ways to make such substitutions (with simplifications as one goes),
restart;
Y__t:=ln(1/X__t-1):
dX__t:=1/2*X__t*(-X__t+1)*(-2*X__t+1)*dt-X__t*(-X__t+1)*dB__t:
dY__t:= diff(Y__t,t)*dt + diff(Y__t,X__t)*dX__t+diff(Y__t,X__t,X__t)*dX__t^2:

First way,
simplify(dY__t,{dB__t*dt=0});
simplify(%,{dB__t^2=dt});
simplify(%,{dt^2=0});

Second way,
simplify(algsubs(dB__t*dt=0,expand(dY__t)));
simplify(algsubs(dB__t^2=dt,%));
simplify(algsubs(dt^2=0,%));


Thank you very much @acer. The solution worked perfectly. However, the simplify function does not simplify dY__t to its simplest form. The resulting expression is correct though not simplified. The simplest form is dY__t = dB__t. Is there a way to simplify the resulting expression to its simplest form?

I don't see how that followup claim in your comment can be true, given the same set of substitutions as you gave originally.

You are very correct @acer. I have made a mistake in writing the expression dY__t := diff(Y__t, t)*dt + diff(Y__t, X__t)*dX__t + diff(Y__t, X__t, X__t)*dX__t^2. I have corrected the expression todY__t := diff(Y__t, t)*dt + diff(Y__t, X__t)*dX__t + 0.5*diff(Y__t, X__t, X__t)*dX__t^2. Kindly check my updated expression. The resulting answer is correct but not in its simplest form. The simplest form is dY__t = dB__t.

The resulting answer is correct but not in its simplest form using the First way. The simplest form is dY__t = dB__t. However I can confirm that the Second way is giving the correct answer in its simplest form. I prefer the First way though it is not simplifying the answer.

For me I get the form of just dB__t using both ways. If you don't directly get the simplest for from the third simplify(...,{...}) (simplify-with-side-relations) in the first method then you might need to follow with just simplify(%). For me both work directly using Maple 2024.0, Maple 16.02, etc. I don't know what version you have.

Thank you very much for assisting. Problem has been resolved. Both the First way and Second way are yielding the simplest form answer. I have accepted the answer.
